# Preventing my script from os command injection python

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

i am using python 2.7.x
I automating my stuffs and in there i need run to another python program from my python script for that i am using the system function from the 'os' library.

for e.g:

```
import os 
os.system("python anotherscript.py --data <USER_INPUT_FROM_MY_SCRIPT_HERE>")
```

so i know if any user inputs some other command in place of expected user input that will be converting to os command injection and that's what i want prevent in this case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to run a Python script from Python, just import it the Python way and invoke the needed function normally

```
import anotherscript

anotherscript.<function>("<user_input>")
```

Answer (score 1):

@Tenchi2xh's answer is the better way to do it, but if that doesn't work (e.g. your script only works on Python 2.x and the other one only works on Python 3.x) then you should use the `subprocess` module, passing the arguments as a list:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', 'anotherscript.py', '--data', '<USER INPUT>'])
```

Also take a look at `subprocess.check_call` and `subprocess.check_output` to see if they are closer to what you need.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call